# Do I need VStack in body for SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      contentView
        .padding()
      
      ToolBarView()
        .padding()
    }
  }
```

I noticed that if I remove `VStack`, the code still works. This is very strange. Are they equivalent? Is `VStack` here implicitly used? If I keep this `VStack`, does it mean that SwiftUI will generate duplicate nested `VStack`?

Edit:

The `contentView` is:

```
  var contentView: some View {
    let state = stateObservable.state
    if state.isResultPage {
      return AnyView(ResultContentView())
    } else {
      return AnyView(JokeContentView())
    }
  }
```

Comment: that depends on what is in  your `contentView` - show the code

Comment: @ChrisR added code

Comment: Though i don't think it's related to what contentView is. My guess is that whatever view the contentView is does not affect the parent view at all.

Comment: ok, that didn't help so much, as now I would ask for resultContentView and JokeContentView :) – let's say it in general: SwiftUI will draw any single view (Text, Image, ForEach, etc ...) in the center of the screen. By using VStack, HStack, ZStack you tell SwiftUI how to arrange multiple views in relation to each other. So the question to your original answer is: You don't need the surrounding VStack.

Comment: So can I say the body is wrapped using VStack by SwiftUI automatically?

Comment: Yes you can say that...

Comment: No, you cannot say that. John didn't give us the name of the `View` type that contains that `body` method. Let's say it's called `JohnView`. Then it is up to the container of the `JohnView` to decide how to lay out the `contentView` and the `ToolBarView`. Some containers use a vertical layout, and others do not. If you always want a vertical layout, say `VStack` explicitly. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid needing to define a `ToolBarView`, I'm going to use this example instead of yours:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("first")
        Text("second")
    }
}
```

So, what is the actual type returned by `MyView().body`? Let's ask Swift:

```
; xcrun swift
Welcome to Swift version 5.5.2-dev.
Type :help for assistance.
  1> import SwiftUI
  2> struct MyView: View { 
  3.     var body: some View { 
  4.         Text("first") 
  5.         Text("second") 
  6.     } 
  7. }
  8> print(type(of: MyView().body))
TupleView<(Text, Text)>
```

It's `TupleView<(Text, Text)>`. So what, exactly, is a [`TupleView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tupleview#)? The documentation says it's

> A View created from a swift tuple of View values.

…That doesn't really explain much. Allow me to explain what `TupleView` is really all about.

SwiftUI uses `TupleView` to represent a collection of views, **without** imposing any specific layout on them. The layout is determined entirely by the container of the `TupleView` (or in this case of the `MyView`). If you always want a vertical layout, you need to use `VStack` explicitly. If you want the container to pick the layout, don't use `VStack`.

If we put the `MyView` in a `VStack`, we get a vertical layout.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(VStack {
    MyView()
})
```

Result:

[image: first above second]

But if we put the `MyView` in an `HStack` then we get a horizontal layout.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(HStack {
    MyView()
})
```

Result:

[image: first to the left of second]

Or we can the `MyView` in a `ControlGroup` and get a different horizontal layout:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ControlGroup {
    MyView()
})
```

Result:

[image: first to the left of second with a divider between them, both Texts dimmed]

If we put the `MyView` inside a `ZStack`, the `Text`s are overlaid.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ZStack {
    MyView()
})
```

Result:

[image: first and second overlaid]

If we put the `MyView` inside a `GeometryReader`, the `Text`s are again overlaid.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(GeometryReader { proxy in
    MyView()
}.frame(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Result:

[image: first and second overlaid at the top left of a white 100 point square]

If we use `MyView` as the body of a `PreviewProvider`, then we get two entirely separate previews.

```
struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: a preview of first above a preview of second]

Comment: This feels like a "spread" operation for a list